# retrieving Programmatically created elements return null

Tags: javascript, html

I create elements and add them to a existing div.

This is the default HTML:

```
<div class="settingsBox" id="settingsBox">
    <p style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    </p>
    <div class="files">
        <div>
            <div class="file">
                <p>File Name</p>
                <p>Password</p>
                <span style="width: min-content;"></span>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

        <div class="fileGroup" id="files"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- <label class="sFile" id="BrowseLabel" for="fileBrowse">
        No Files Selected
    </label> -->
    <textarea placeholder="Request Description" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <hr>
</div>

<button type="button" id="submit" class="submitBtn">
    <span id="psize">Submit Request</span>
</button>
```

On the `onChange` of input:

```
function fileChange(file) {
    let destGroup = document.getElementById("files");

    Object.keys(file).forEach(i => {

        let index = ++filesList.lastKey;

        filesList[index] = {};
        filesList[index].file = file[i];

        let fileName = file[i].name;

        let div = document.createElement("div");
        let sFileDiv =
            `<div id="FileListFile:${index}" class="file" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                <div style="display: flex;">
                    <p onclick="removeFile(this);" style="padding: 0px; margin-right:10px; cursor: pointer;">&times;</p>
                    <p>${setFileNameLabel(fileName)}</p>
                </div>                                
            </div>`;

        div.innerHTML = sFileDiv;

        destGroup.appendChild(div);

        if (fileName.split(".").pop() === "pdf") {
            verifyEncription(filesList[index].file, "", true, index);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("FileListFile:" + index).insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<p>Ready</p>`);
            filesList[index] = { isVerified: "true" }
        }

    });
    console.log(filesList);
}
```

then in the verification of password in pdfjs.get document if the file is encrypted:

```
filesList[index].isVerified = "false";
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.id = index;
input.type = "text";
input.placeholder = "Enter Password";

input.addEventListener("focusout", function (evt) {
    verifyEncription(filesList[index].file, evt.target, false, index);
});

input.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
    if (evt.key == "Enter") {
        verifyEncription(filesList[index].file, evt.target, false, index)
    }
});
input.classList.add("passInput");
document.getElementById("FileListFile:" + index).appendChild(input);
```

But when i try to retrieve the document to add a class then it's returned value is null

```
function uploadClick() {
    let i = Object.keys(filesList);
    i.forEach(index => {
        let cIndex = filesList[index];
        if (cIndex.isVerified) {
            if (cIndex.password !== undefined) {
                cIndex.file = getRenamedfile(cIndex.file, cIndex.password);
                alert(cIndex.file.name);
            }
        } else {
            let doc =document.getElemenetById(index);
            passWarning("add", doc)
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

`document.getElementById()` it returns null.

the script is loading at the bottom.
the button click happens after the creation of the elements as the button is the final upload button.

The elements are there as i check it by printing the `innerhtml` of `parentNode.parentNode` of
the `createdElement` or the Main container div.

`console.log(document.getElementById("files"));`

and the result was this:

```
<div>
    <div id="FileListFile:0" class="file" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <p onclick="removeFile(this);" style="padding: 0px; margin-right:10px; cursor: pointer;">×</p>
            <p>FileToUpload.pdf</p>
        </div>
        <input id="0" type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" class="passInput">
    </div>
</div>
```

why i cannot retrive the element ?

Comment: You don't appear to have any element with an id of "files".

Comment: can you create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem - you don't seem to have the vital code that isn't working (ie the button click trying to get your element)

Comment: @GordonKushner and Pete i've updated the code with all the relative information and code such as button click preexisting html or non-programmatically created html. Please Take a look. The thing i am doing is selecting multiple files and adding them to a list to show password field if the pdf is encrypted and upload it. the code does not includes the upload part as that is not concern right now.